# Do two numbers contain unique powers of 2

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, decision-problem, integer, bitwise

Break two numbers up into their powers of 2, if they share any, return a falsey value. Otherwise, return a truthy value.

If one input is `0`, the answer will always be truthy.
if one input is `255`, the answer will be falsey if the other is not `0`.

## Example

Given 5 and 3

```
5 = 2⁰ + 2²
3 = 2⁰ + 2¹
```

Both share 2⁰, return falsey.

Given 8 and 17

```
8  = 2³
17 = 2⁰ + 2⁴
```

Neither share any powers, return truthy.

## I/O

Input and output can be through [any standard means](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Input will always be two integers in the range `0 <= n <= 255`

Output should be one [truthy or falsey value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey)

## Test Cases

```
Truthy:
1, 2
3, 4
2, 4
8, 17
248, 7

Falsey:
1, 3
6, 4
8, 8
```

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Can I output 0 for truthy and 1 for falsey instead?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Although it often depends on the language as to what counts as Truthy or Falsey, this is usually acceptable. EDIT: Read the comment wrong, backwards output is not acceptable.

Comment: Do all truthy inputs have to result in the same truthy value?

Comment: @Dennis They can be different values, as long as they are Truthy/Falsey

Comment: May we take inputs in binary?

Comment: If your language's default number system is binary sure, otherwise, you should use the language's default.

Comment: This challenge is [way too trivial](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/too-trivial-close-vote).

Comment: Is there a language with a 1-byte NAND built-in? If so, it will win.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
&Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/18t8v9/Cy5DcwA)

Explanation:

```
&Y
&   bitwise AND
 Y  boolean negation
```

Answer (score 7):

## x86 Machine Code, 5 bytes

```
20 C8 0F 95 C0
```

takes inputs in `al` and `cl`, and returns output in `al`, and is equivalent to:

```
and al, cl
setnz al
```

Comment: You could make this follow a standard calling convention (specifically, the Windows 64-bit calling convention, or Windows 32-bit __fastcall) by receiving the parameters in `cl` and `dl`. The `setnz al` instruction would remain the same, since a result is always returned in `eax` (or sub-portions thereof). That doesn't change the code size any at all, but makes the code a bit more real-world and callable from other languages.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
&¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/t0Jr///9b/Dc0BwA)

Explanation:

```
&¬
&   bitwise AND
 ¬  logical negation
```

Comment: I was expecting this to be easy, but I didn't think of `&`, I was not expecting this to be two bytes easy.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a&b<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X9cuUSepOlEtycaw9n@JLTKXq0ChJNpCx9A89j8A)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
BitAnd@##<1&
```

Pure function taking two positive integers as argument and returning `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:not a&b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSFRJ8kqL79EIVEt6X@BLaYgV0FRZl6JRoGGhY6huabmfwA)

Comment: [2 bytes saved](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqUS3JxvB/Wn6RQklqcYlCZp6ChoahjoKRpo6ChrGOggmINoLSFjoKhuZgARMgE8wCKjUG0WYIJRaamlZcnAVFmXklGiAzdRTSNLRADE3N/wA) using `<1` rather than `not `.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 10 bytes

```bash
!(($1&$2))
```

Input is via command-line arguments. Output is via exit code, so **0** is truthy and **1** if falsy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X1FDQ8VQTcVIU/P///@G/40B)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
&_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fLf7/fwsuQ3MA)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 28 bytes

```
f=function(a,b)!bitwAnd(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 12 bytes

```
a=>b=>!(a&b)
```

Takes input in the currying format.

```js
let f=

a=>b=>!(a&b)

console.log(f(1)(2));
console.log(f(3)(4));
console.log(f(2)(4));
console.log(f(8)(17));
console.log(f(248)(7));
console.log(f(1)(3));
console.log(f(6)(4));
console.log(f(8)(8));
```

Comment: 1B saved: `a=>b=>a&b<1`

Comment: @Luke That outputs 0 for all the testcases. In order to make that work I would have to surround `a&b` with parentheses.

Comment: Oh, nvm then...

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>23</s> 4 bytes

```
q~&!
```

It turns out my previous solution contained an implementation of what was essentially just bitwise AND (which is silly because it used `&` anyway).

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
{&!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flFmU@b9aTbH2f91/IxMLBXMA)

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124643/61384

Comment: @Challenger5 Damn you grace period!

Answer (score 1):

## R, 23 bytes

if allowed - this version can get multiple inputs as a1,a2,a3..... b1,b2,b3.....

```
!bitwAnd(scan(),scan())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 3 bytes

```
~&!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05N8f9/IxMLBXMA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 3 bytes

```
.&!
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.%26%21&input=3%0A1&warnings=0)

```
.&  -  bitwise_and(input_1, input_2)
  ! - not ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 3 bytes

```
Z&~
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=Z%26%7E&inputs=8%0A17&version=20.0.0).

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab both inputs
Z&  % Bit-wise AND
~   % Negate the result and implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 80 bytes

```
 AZ BZ CZ DZ EZ FZ GZ HZ
,[',[',[',[',[',[',[',['*Z~S
`--)--)--)--)--)--)--)~aef
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/X8ExSsEpSsE5SsElSsE1SsEtSsE9SsEjiksnWh0r0oqqC@ZK0NXVxER1ialp//87qgAA)

Takes input as two consecutive bytes. (In the TIO, the characters 'A' and '$' are used, corresponding to values 65 and 36.)

This solution has eight chunks, one per bit, plus an extra chunk at the end. Looking at these chunks:

`A` is bit `0x01` of the input. (The letters `A` though `H` correspond to a bit each.) `Z` holds on to a value for the next cycle while producing the previous value. Hence, `A` and `Z` are the current and previous values of bit `0x01`.

`[` is an AND-gate; it simply ANDs its two inputs together. So the full row of such gates is performing a bitwise AND of the two bytes.

Finally, `)` is an OR-gate. All eight AND results are OR'd together, giving us a True is there is a match, and a False otherwise. We want the inverse of that, so use a NOT-gate (`~`) before passing it to the output.

We output via `a`, `e`, and `f`. The `a`, which corresponds to bit `0x01` of the output,  receives the result of the above computation. The other two bits `e` and `f` are unconditionally on, together forming `0x30`. Therefore, the output is either `0x30` or `0x31`, which are the codes for ASCII characters '0' and '1'.

The extra stuff is housekeeping, it prevents output for the first cycle (there is no previous value at this point, so there is no reason to do a comparison).

---

#### Alternate solution, also 80 bytes

```
A~.B~.C~.D~.E~.F~.G~.H~.
Z~<Z~<Z~<Z~<Z~<Z~<Z~<Z~<*Z~S
 a[--[--[--[--[--[--[--'ef
```

This is very similar in style, but uses a different algorithm. Where above we AND each pair of bits, and use OR to reduce the result to a single value, here we OR the negation of each pair of bits, then use AND to reduce.

One thing to note: we use an implicit OR here, instead of a proper gate as above. We could have used implicit OR'ing above as well, but there is no byte-savings there.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 13 bytes

```
a->b->(a&b)<1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>87</s> <s>85</s> <s>87</s> 80 bytes

+2 bytes to correct an error pointed out by [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

-7 bytes thanks to [@aiden-chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)

```
D(n)=mod(floor(n/2^{[0...floor(log_2(n+0^n))]}),2)
f(a,b)=\{\total(D(a)D(b))=0\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mf12qkvyda)

**f** returns `1` when they are "truthy" and otherwise `undefined`.

Comment: nice! for it to paste correctly, `{...}` needs to be `\{...\}`, and `\log_{2}n` can just be `log2n`.

Comment: @Steffan Yeah I forgot, it should have been `\{...\}`.
For me, log2n doesn't work btw.

Comment: Well it can still be `log_2n`.

Comment: `\{...\}` won't paste correctly if the built-in functions don't have backslashes in front of them. In this case, you need to replace `total` with `\total`.

Comment: But there are a few golfs you can do: [74 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odsnlwn2gm). Namely, I utilized a golfier way to convert to binary which only uses `2^{[0...floor(log_2n)]}` once, so both `X` and `W` are not needed.

Comment: Actually, your code doesn't handle `0` input correctly, so you will need to replace `floor(log_2n)` with `floor(log_2(n+0^n))`, which brings up the byte count to 80 bytes.

Comment: @AidenChow great 

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 10 bytes

```
|a,b|a&b<1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMFNo7Q8hdzEzDwNTYVqLs6c1BKFRAVbBSNrCDsJyDYEsguKMvNKFDWUqmuVdDSWlpak6VqsqknUSapJVEuyMYQIrOHU1EjUUUjS1LTmqoUILVgAoQE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
x->y->!bitand(x,y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8L9C165S104xKbMkMS9Fo0KnUvN/QVFmXolGmoahpoaRpiYXjGusqWGCxDVC5VpoahiaI0ubAEWQBYCmGSNxzTC0W2hq/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 28

```
(a,b)=>!(256&(-~a|-~b)||a&b)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 12 bytes

```
?(: and :)=0
```

This returns `-1` for truthy inputs, and `0`otherwise. "Bitwise" is something QBasic isn't very good at, and I haven't built any of this stuff into QBIC either.

Answer (score 0):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 13 bytes

```
(x,y)=>!(x&y)
```

Here, `(arg1,...)=>result` is [the D lambda syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8857965/1488799), and the `!` and `&` are common notations for boolean negation and bitwise AND.

You can find the whole program coupled with the tests [at tio.run](https://tio.run/##HY1rCoMwEIT/7ymmQiULUjBKFSS9SyRKAz6KplUpnj1NOuzAMgzfGK8Hq1f07wnKiz07WD0uYk8P9g19ZmswajtBMH0JsONrXhxWZ27Bdm5iNjnoDG38t6cdOoil06aHSHBdwyUZ0lBIW4ZSkBx6kRW0LdZ1Q6DHeREhzBFz0kk@h6QCJcngGnlFsqxREeUo6P7PavoB).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 25 Bytes

print 1 for true and nothing for false

```
<?=!($argv[1]&+$argv[2]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WUUMlsSi9LNowVk0bwjKK1bT@//@/icF/EwA)

Comment: `<?=+!($argv[1]&$argv[2]);` -2 bytes

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista  Yes then the arguments must cast from string to integer.Otherwise `40&4` is false and `"40"&"4"` is true for example

Comment: what about removing just one of the two? it worked with `40&4`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista right that cast both values to integer Thank You

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 19 bytes

```lua
a,b=...print(a&b<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/USfJVk9Pr6AoM69EI1EtycZQ8////6b/jQE)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 18 bytes

Uses exit-code 0 as truthy.

```c
f(a,b){exit(a&b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM6tSKzRCNRLUnTuvZ/bmJmnoZmdZqGhY6hOUgAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
!.&hQe
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21.%26hQe&input=248%2C7&debug=0)

**Explanations**

```
!.&hQe

   hQ     Get first input number
     e    Get second (implicit) input number
 .&       Bitwise and
!         Negate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise), 11 bytes

```
&::^~![&&]|
```

Due to a bug this does not currently work on tio, however it does work on the desktop version.

Here is a slightly longer version that works for both:

```
&::^~![?~&:]|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K88sTv3/X83KKq5OMdq@Ts0qtub///8W/y0A)

## Explanation

Most of our code goes into a logical not, in fact only the first byte is required if you want to get the *opposite* answer.

```
&             #Bitwise and
 ::^~![?~&:]| #Logical not
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 34 bytes

```
-- Begin test cases
WITH T (x, y, desired) AS (
  SELECT   1,  2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   3,  4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   2,  4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8, 17, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 248,  7, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   1,  3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   6,  4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   8,  8, 0 FROM DUAL)
-- End test cases
SELECT T.*, -SIGN(BITAND(x, y)) + 1 result FROM T
/
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 10 bytes

```
 ∧/⍲/⎕⊤⍨8⍴2
```

Take two (or more) numbers, convert them to binary, then apply the NAND to pairs of bits, then reduce by conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 30 bytes

```go
func(a,b int)any{return a&b<1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVBRasJAEMUvcU8xBCwJTItRaYOYnqH_McgouxI0G9lsArLkJP0JhV6j99DTuOsKQulPv95jeO_NvPn82lX9GY603dOOQ0mFZEV5rJSGQJQ6YC0pEOl3o8Vz8iMauQ0JN1BIHZE8GcV1oyTQ02YZd150GQyd7BYVRmCYVg2vYZFClme5NRpmYoRph8zMEOYOp3dMEOK322BuqWMdE3Soef3bPnOq14ct8dpKwRq5W6ZI2j5-t2Ej2-XlQ1m7CINxC-k7jNuVDBA4ggh5NsmRZ3EeRX-l-BP-G3P_R997vAI)